# Can I bring my wife to Austria on a dependent visa?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, dependent-visa, austria

I am from India and I have visa D (long term visa) which will expire in September 2018.

I want to bring my spouse to Austria on a dependent visa. Can I bring her here for more than 90 days? What is the procedure?

Comment: The answer to this question apparently [depends on the basis for your D visa](https://www.migration.gv.at/en/types-of-immigration/temporary-residence/).  What is the basis of your D visa?

Answer (score 1):

VISA D has 3 sub categories. Non of which makes you eligible to get your spouse in Austria. However she can always apply on her own individual criteria to make a tour of Austria.

But, If you are planning to get a resident permit in Austria, then your spouse is eligible to join you under family re-unification visa.

Comment: Ohh.. so she can apply for 3 months visa which is a type of Visa C? I don't think I can apply for the resident permit so I think only one option available for us.

Comment: Yes she can get the C VISA if all the conditions are met. You will get all the details (including visa form) in the following website.
http://www.vfs-austria.co.in/